# Does the network of $X$ equal to the network of $C_p(X)$?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Does the network of $X$ equal to the network of $C_p(X)$?

$C_p(X)$ denotes the set of all real-valued continuous functions on $X$ endowed with the topology of pointwise convergence.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean network *weight*?

Comment: @Emil Jerabek: Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is Theorem I.1.3 in *Topological Function Spaces* by A.V. Arkhangelski:

> For any space $X$, $nw(X)=nw(C_p(X))$.

Where $nw(X)$ denotes the network weight of $X$ (i.e. the minimal cardinality of a network in $X$).